# Fetch data from multiple tables in django views

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In Django views, I want to fetch all details(Workeraccount.location,Workeravail.date, Workerprofile.*) for any particular wid=1.

SQL Query:

```
select * from Workeraccount,Workeravail,Workerprofile where Workerprofile.wid=1 and Workerprofile.wid=Workeravail.wid and Workeraccount.wid=Workerprofile.wid;
```

The corresponding models are as follows:

```
class Workeraccount(models.Model):
    wid = models.ForeignKey('Workerprofile', db_column='wid', unique=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, db_column='location')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'workerAccount'

class Workeravail(models.Model):
    wid = models.ForeignKey('Workerprofile', db_column='wid')
    date = models.DateField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'workerAvail'

class Workerprofile(models.Model):
    wid = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'workerProfile'`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
workprofile = Workerprofile.objects.filter(id=1).first()
all_worker_avails = workprofile.workeravail_set.all()
all_workeraccounts = workprofile.workeraccount_set.all()
```

As `Workeraccount` and `Workeravail` are related through `Workerprofile`, you can get one queryset easily - you will need two separate ones.

You can also do the following:

```
all_worker_avails = Workeravail.objects.filter(wid=workprofile)
...
```

Comment: I am getting error as 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'workeraccount', query executed:

obj=Workerprofile.objects.all()
workavail=obj.workeraccount.objects.all().

Comment: Do you have tab completion? If you do `workprofile.` + tab what do you see? I updated my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with only one database call:

```
workprofile = Workerprofile.objects.get(pk=1)
    .select_related('workeravail_set', 'workerprofile_set')
```

This will fetch all the data for you at once, which can then be used with:

```
workprofile.workerprofile_set.location #Gets the Workeraccount.location
workprofile.workeravail_set.date       #Gets the Workeravail.date
workprofile.fname                      #Example of Workerprofile.*
```

As an aside, if you want a shorter way to reference the foreign objects than the "*_set" method, you can set a related_name like

```
class Workeraccount(models.Model):
    wid = models.ForeignKey('Workerprofile', db_column='wid', unique=True, related_name='waccount')
    ...
```

And then replace `workeraccount_set` with `waccount`